# Python DETAIL: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

im trying to add a string to an ArrayField and I'm getting `DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.` error.

this is how the model looks like the method update_credential is where im trying to add the merchant_id to merchants ArrayField.

```py
class CloverCredential(models.Model):
    tenant = models.OneToOneField('tenant.Tenant', unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = EncryptedCharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    spreedly_receiver_token = EncryptedCharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    merchants = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True), null=True)

    def update_credential(self, new_token, merchant_id):
        self.token = new_token
        self.merchants = merchant_id
        self.save()
```

This is the view where im calling update_credential and passing token and `merchant_id`

```py
class OAuthCallback(APIView):
    def api_request(self, path):
        return requests.get(path).json()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        code = request.GET.get('code', '')
        state = unsign_state(request.GET.get('state', ''))
        merchant_id = request.GET.get('merchant_id', '')
        tenant = get_object_or_404(Tenant, pk=state['tenant_id'])
        clover_credential, created = CloverCredential.objects.get_or_create(tenant=tenant)

        url = f'{settings.CLOVER_URL_US}/oauth/token?client_id={settings.CLOVER_APP_ID}&client_secret={settings.CLOVER_APP_SECRET}&code={code}'
        oauth_response = self.api_request(url)
        clover_credential.update_credential(oauth_response['access_token'], merchant_id)
        return redirect(state['redirect'])
```

i also tried to append merchant_id to merchants 
`self.merchants.append(merchant_id)`
and got this error
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem**

The field `merchants` is a list but by default it is null.

**Solution**

So the best things to do is set a `default=list`.

**Error Explanation**

> Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.

This occurs because you are puttting a variable inside a list, instead do this `self.merchants = [merchant_id, ]`

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

This occurs because you have a None, not a list. Make an empty list the default value or set it by code: `self.merchants = list()`

Answer (score 0):

Further to this, my context was adding an ArrayField to a Django model, and on initial migration failing because I was passing it a string as a default, which the migration file referenced and failed out on when it interfaced with PSQL.

Solved this by hand-editing the migration file, finding the initial migration default string and putting brackets around the string.

Doesn't happen on future instances as I think the ArrayField implementation explicitly casts a comma separated list with brackets as part of the save operation, just not on the initial migration if it's expecting a default.